# Android Studio won't let me "Install repository and sync project"

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, firebaseui

I tried installing FirebaseUI and now I'm having this gradle errors. I tried installing the libraries that gradle is telling me in the build.gradle file but Android Studio is giving me this error and it doesn't let me press "Install repository and sync project".

[Error given by gradle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gikRS.png)

Here's is my build.gradle file

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.avantefg.avante"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    signingConfigs {
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile('com.digits.sdk.android:digits:2.0.2@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile('com.mikepenz:materialdrawer:5.8.0@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
    dependencies {
        compile 'com.getbase:floatingactionbutton:1.10.1'
    }
    //Lollipin
    compile('com.github.orangegangsters:lollipin:2.0.0@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.7@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }

    compile 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
    compile 'com.wang.avi:library:2.1.3'
    compile 'jp.wasabeef:blurry:2.0.3'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:2.2.0'
    compile 'io.github.yuweiguocn:SquareLoading:1.3.0'

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-beta4'
    compile 'com.android.support:customtabs:25.3.1'



    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.cocosw:bottomsheet:1.+@aar'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.4.2'
    compile 'com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:2.7.0-beta.1'
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.4.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Here's the project build.grade file

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'



        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven{
            url "https://github.com/omadahealth/omada-nexus/raw/master/release"
        }
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Please someone help me!

Comment: Can you post your project level build.gradle?

Comment: Yes! I just added it!

Comment: check your interenet connection

Answer (score 0):

Recently, Google start to distribute android support library by maven repo.

You can try add

```
maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
```

in your project level build.gradle

example:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.3-2'
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-alpha9'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'http://devrepo.kakao.com:8088/nexus/content/groups/public/' 
}
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Friend the most solution for the "install repository and sync project" is Go to **File>Invalidate Cache/Restart** you will be shown a window asking to confirm restart.Be aware that local history will be cleared. 
if that does not check the library version that u installed and change it what u have.

Answer (score 0):

Here your dependency was not matching with your BuildTools so you need to give dependency as per your you build tool version for the resolution you need to remove all dependency or add from Project structure or else change version name as per build version like following,

Like I have already  install build tool 25.0.1 and I give dependency like `compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.0.2'` So I need to change like `compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.0.1'` So It will work.

Comment: Ok, I'm using buildToolsVersion "25.0.3" and FirebaseUI says that I need to use 'com.android.support:customtabs:25.4.0' but if I tried to change my buildToolsVersion to 25.4.0 Android Studio tells me that that version doesn't exist. Maybe I need to use and older version of FirebaseUI????

Comment: If you update your build tools version then it's good. And If it is not possible from studio then you can update using SDK manager then after set your latest dependancy.

Comment: I fixed it! It turns out that I just needed to update my gradle to the lasted version!

Comment: Okay Nice, Good Job

Comment: Thanks for the help!